How to debounce text in swiftui and also assign when the view is closed?
I am writing a text editing field that autosaves to a server. I wrote this helper view to make debouncing such views simple.
The trick is I need to support when there is an initial value or when a new value is generated outside of the text field.
This code works well but one problem it has is it does not update the debouncedText on closing of the view. Given my debounce period is 10 seconds this means its quite easy to close the view without the output debouncedText being written to.
class TextDebounceObserver : ObservableObject {
    @Published var debouncedText = ""
    @Published var text = ""
    
    init(delay: DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride) {
        $text
            .debounce(for: delay, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .dropFirst()
            .assign(to: &$debouncedText)
    }
}


struct DebouncingTextEditor: View {
    @State private var textObserver: TextDebounceObserver
    
    @Binding var debouncedText: String
    
    init(debouncedText: Binding<String>, delay: DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride) {
        self._debouncedText = debouncedText
        self.textObserver = TextDebounceObserver(delay: delay)
        self.textObserver.text = debouncedText.wrappedValue
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $textObserver.text)
            .onReceive(textObserver.$debouncedText.dropFirst()) { (newText) in
                debouncedText = newText
            }
            .onChange(of: debouncedText) { oldValue, newValue in
                self.textObserver.text = newValue
            }
    }
}

Perhaps is there a way with combine to have it detect when that debounce is canceled/de-initialized and then manually set debouncedText there?
Here's how it is used
DebouncingTextEditor(debouncedText: $saveText, delay: .seconds(10))
   .onChange(of: viewModel.proposalMessage.body) {
      saveMessageToServer()
   }


You can simply detect the view "closing" (what exactly do you mean by that?) and assign to debouncedText manually.

How do I detect that? I have seen a number of ways but none of them really work here.

Please define what you mean by "closing" first. Do you mean going back to the home screen? Or navigating to another view in a NavigationStack? Or is this in a sheet and the sheet is dismissed? For the latter two you can use onDisappear and for the first one you can use onChange(of: scenePhase).

The way to know when the view disappears is the @StateObject will deinit the ObservableObject however that is getting complicated so I would go with .task instead of ObservableObject, e.g.
@Binding var debouncedText: String
@State var text = ""
...
     TextEditor(text: $text)
         .onAppear {
             text = debouncedText // for setting initial text
         }
         .task(id: text) { // runs on appear and is cancelled on disappear and restarted when id changes.
             if text == debouncedText { return }
             do {
                 try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(10))
             }
             catch {} // view closed, cancel exception thrown
             debouncedText = text
         }

